# UIButton/UIView.animate make buttons blink in sequence

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm making a simon game in swift where the signals are given in enum [Green,Yellow,Red,Red,Blue]... and I want to make the buttons blink as the signals are given. The code I used to make the buttons blink is

```swift
extension UIButton {
    func blink() {
        self.alpha = 0.0;
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, //Time duration you want,
            delay: 0.0,
            options: [.curveEaseInOut, .autoreverse],
            animations: { [weak self] in self?.alpha = 1.0 },
            completion: { [weak self] _ in self?.alpha = 1.0 })
    }
}
```

and in my give signal function, I am doing

```swift
    func giveSignal() {
        disableButton()
        signals = []
        for _ in 0...levelNum  {
//            stopBlinkAll()
            let randomSignal:Int = randomSource.nextInt(upperBound: 4)
            switch randomSignal {
                //Green
                case 0:
                    green.blink()
                    signals.append(Block.green)
//                    green.stopBlink()
                //Red
                case 1:
                    red.blink()
                    signals.append(Block.red)
//                    red.stopBlink()
                //Yellow
                case 2:
                    yellow.blink()
                    signals.append(Block.yellow)
//                    yellow.stopBlink()
                //Blue
                case 3:
                    blue.blink()
                    signals.append(Block.blue)
//                    blue.stopBlink()
            default:
                break
            }

        }
        let finalSeq:String = makeString()
        statusBar.text = finalSeq
    }
```

But if the signals are given as [Green,Yellow,Red] for example, all the green, yellow, red buttons blink at the same time. How can I fix this to make the buttons blink one after the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add a completion handler to `blink`, because we are only going to start the next blink after the previous blink has finished.

```
extension UIButton {
    func blink(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.alpha = 0.0;
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, //Time duration you want,
            delay: 0.0,
            options: [.curveEaseInOut],
            animations: { self.alpha = 1.0 },
            completion: { _ in
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6,
                    delay: 0.0,
                    options: [.curveEaseInOut],
                    animations: { self.alpha = 0.0 },
                    completion: { _ in completion() })
             })
    }
}
```

Then, write a function that takes in a `[Block]` and an index, that blinks the button at that index. Note how I pass the closure that calls `blink(at:in:)` again as the completion of the `blink()` calls:

```
func blink(at index: Int, in signals: [Block]) {
    guard index < signals.count else { return }
    let completion = { blink(at: index + 1, in: signals) }

    switch (signals[index]) {
        case .green: green.blink(completion: completion)
        case .red: red.blink(completion: completion)
        case .yellow: yellow.blink(completion: completion)
        case .blue: blue.blink(completion: completion)
    }
}
```

Now, we can rewrite `giveSignal`:

```
func giveSignal() {
    disableButton()
    signals = []
    for _ in 0...levelNum  {
        let randomSignal:Int = randomSource.nextInt(upperBound: 4)
        switch randomSignal {
        //Green
        case 0:
            signals.append(Block.green)
        //Red
        case 1:
            signals.append(Block.red)
        //Yellow
        case 2:
            signals.append(Block.yellow)
        //Blue
        case 3:
            signals.append(Block.blue)
        default:
            break
        }

    }
    blink(at: 0, in: signals) // This starts the sequence of blinks
    let finalSeq:String = makeString()
    statusBar.text = finalSeq
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! Also my blink animation is quite choppy and blinks like twice. do you know how to make it more clean? I just want one simple blink.

Comment: @JiwooLee Apparently, `autoreverse` [must be combined with `repeat`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/animationoptions/1622639-autoreverse). So I think you should run 2 animations in the `blink()` method instead of using `autoreverse`.

Comment: @JiwooLee See the edit. I have changed `blink` to not use `autoreverse`.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you again :)